# Reorder TreeMap after remove()

Tags: java, treemap

I have a `treeMap` that contains `guestbookEntries`. The keys are used for ordering and pagination. I have the problem that when I delete an entry, the `size()` of the `guestbookEntries` decreases, which results in posts being overwritten for example because I am creating new entries with a key of `guestbookEntries.size() + 1`.

In order to change this I would like to reorder my `TreeMap` so that when I remove a key-value-pair. The number of all the following keys is decreased by one, so there should be no "gap" within the `TreeMap` resulting in `guestbookEntries.size()` being correct again.

I was thinking of something like that, where `postNumber` is the key of the entry that was removed.

```
for(int i = postNumber; i < guestbookEntries.size(); i++) {
            Guestbook gb = guestbookEntries.get(i + 1);
            guestbookEntries.put(postNumber, gb);
            guestbookEntries.remove(postNumber + 1);
}
```

Is there an easier way of doing that?

Comment: This doesn't answer to your question, but why use a TreeMap ? Why not a Guestbook array (or ArrayList) ?

Comment: I initially used it because it was ordered automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that this solution is actually very bad idea. Imagine that you would like to create numbering of posts in your guest book. Somebody else would like to reference to that posts by its `id`. But when you are shifting your posts back, decreasing theirs `id`s you doing probably problems for that person, who wants reference posts.

Furthermore, imagine, that somebody deletes post #0, and there are already 100,000 posts in your guestbook. Your program then will have to shift 99,999 post objects in your tree map, decreasing their numbers.

The only possible good solution in this case, do not use `guestbookEntries.size() + 1` as basis for generating new post's id.

Instead of this just create some static integer field, it will be good solution to use some concurrent-ready class, for example `AtomicInteger`.

```
static AtomicInteger postIdGenerator = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

The only thing which you will have to do for resolving `id` for new post, is: `postIdGenerator.incrementAndGet()`.